# Setting the output directory of mex files in the compiler command

Tags: matlab, mex

My Project has the following structure:

```
MainFolder:
  >>InitToolbox.m     //Here addpaths are executed
  >>Compile.m         //Here mex compilations calls are made
    AlgorithmsFolder  //MATLAB code
    UtilitiesFolder   //MATLAB code
    MexFolder         // C++ files
       >>test1.cpp
       >>test2.cu
```

Whever I run (either in `compile.m` or directly in the command line) the following compiler call:

```
mex -v -largeArrayDims ./MexFolder/test1.cpp ./MexFolder/test2.cu
```

The output `test1.mexw64` is saved in `MainFolder`.

**Is there any way to modify the compiler call to create the `.mexw64` file either on the original location of the files or in an specific user defined location?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to specify the output directory using the `outdir` option for [`mex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html)

```
mex -v -largeArrayDims ./MexFolder/test1.cpp ./MexFolder/test2.cu -outdir output_directory
```

"output_directory" above can be any path you want.

It can also be a variable, but that would require you to update the way you're calling `mex`

```
outputFolder = 'path/to/folder';

mex('-v', '-largeArrayDims', 'MexFolder/test1.cpp', ...
    'MexFolder/test2.cu', '-outdir', outputFolder);
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! for some reason my intense Googling did not show the mex option webpage!

Comment: You have a typo in your code example at the bottom of your answer: you have `-outputdir` when it should be `-outdir`, as you correctly say at the top of the answer.